# Why am I getting this error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'binance.client'; 'binance' is not a package' after binance installed?

Tags: python, binance

I am using visual studio code to try and pull candles from binance but i keep getting the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'binance.client'; 'binance' is not a package
```

heres the line of code that is causing the error:

```
from binance.client import Client
```

Ive made sure that I pip installed python-binance to the right version of python and from what ive read im guessing theres something wrong with the path but im not sure what to look for. I ran the following code check the path

```
import pprint, os
import binance

pprint.pprint(os.path.abspath(binance.__file__))
```

this was my result

```
'/Users/myName/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/binance.py'
```

i read that having files named binance.py could mess with it, but this was the name given when it was downloaded. if your curious about what it looks like here it is:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import logging
import requests
import time
try:
    from urllib import urlencode

# for python3
except ImportError:
    from urllib.parse import urlencode


ENDPOINT = "https://www.binance.com"

BUY = "BUY"
SELL = "SELL"

LIMIT = "LIMIT"
MARKET = "MARKET"

GTC = "GTC"
IOC = "IOC"

options = {}


def set(apiKey, secret):
    """Set API key and secret.

    Must be called before any making any signed API calls.
    """
    options["apiKey"] = apiKey
    options["secret"] = secret


def prices():
    """Get latest prices for all symbols."""
    data = request("GET", "/api/v1/ticker/allPrices")
    return {d["symbol"]: d["price"] for d in data}


def tickers():
    """Get best price/qty on the order book for all symbols."""
    data = request("GET", "/api/v1/ticker/allBookTickers")
    return {d["symbol"]: {
        "bid": d["bidPrice"],
        "ask": d["askPrice"],
        "bidQty": d["bidQty"],
        "askQty": d["askQty"],
    } for d in data}


def depth(symbol, **kwargs):
    """Get order book.

    Args:
        symbol (str)
        limit (int, optional): Default 100. Must be one of 50, 20, 100, 500, 5,
            200, 10.

    """
    params = {"symbol": symbol}
    params.update(kwargs)
    data = request("GET", "/api/v1/depth", params)
    return {
        "bids": {px: qty for px, qty, _ in data["bids"]},
        "asks": {px: qty for px, qty, _ in data["asks"]},
    }


def klines(symbol, interval, **kwargs):
    """Get kline/candlestick bars for a symbol.

    Klines are uniquely identified by their open time. If startTime and endTime
    are not sent, the most recent klines are returned.

    Args:
        symbol (str)
        interval (str)
        limit (int, optional): Default 500; max 500.
        startTime (int, optional)
        endTime (int, optional)

    """
    params = {"symbol": symbol, "interval": interval}
    params.update(kwargs)
    data = request("GET", "/api/v1/klines", params)
    return [{
        "openTime": d[0],
        "open": d[1],
        "high": d[2],
        "low": d[3],
        "close": d[4],
        "volume": d[5],
        "closeTime": d[6],
        "quoteVolume": d[7],
        "numTrades": d[8],
    } for d in data]


def balances():
    """Get current balances for all symbols."""
    data = signedRequest("GET", "/api/v3/account", {})
    if 'msg' in data:
        raise ValueError("Error from exchange: {}".format(data['msg']))

    return {d["asset"]: {
        "free": d["free"],
        "locked": d["locked"],
    } for d in data.get("balances", [])}


def order(symbol, side, quantity, price, orderType=LIMIT, timeInForce=GTC,
          test=False, **kwargs):
    """Send in a new order.

    Args:
        symbol (str)
        side (str): BUY or SELL.
        quantity (float, str or decimal)
        price (float, str or decimal)
        orderType (str, optional): LIMIT or MARKET.
        timeInForce (str, optional): GTC or IOC.
        test (bool, optional): Creates and validates a new order but does not
            send it into the matching engine. Returns an empty dict if
            successful.
        newClientOrderId (str, optional): A unique id for the order.
            Automatically generated if not sent.
        stopPrice (float, str or decimal, optional): Used with stop orders.
        icebergQty (float, str or decimal, optional): Used with iceberg orders.

    """
    params = {
        "symbol": symbol,
        "side": side,
        "type": orderType,
        "timeInForce": timeInForce,
        "quantity": formatNumber(quantity),
        "price": formatNumber(price),
    }
    params.update(kwargs)
    path = "/api/v3/order/test" if test else "/api/v3/order"
    data = signedRequest("POST", path, params)
    return data


def orderStatus(symbol, **kwargs):
    """Check an order's status.

    Args:
        symbol (str)
        orderId (int, optional)
        origClientOrderId (str, optional)
        recvWindow (int, optional)

    """
    params = {"symbol": symbol}
    params.update(kwargs)
    data = signedRequest("GET", "/api/v3/order", params)
    return data


def cancel(symbol, **kwargs):
    """Cancel an active order.

    Args:
        symbol (str)
        orderId (int, optional)
        origClientOrderId (str, optional)
        newClientOrderId (str, optional): Used to uniquely identify this
            cancel. Automatically generated by default.
        recvWindow (int, optional)

    """
    params = {"symbol": symbol}
    params.update(kwargs)
    data = signedRequest("DELETE", "/api/v3/order", params)
    return data


def openOrders(symbol, **kwargs):
    """Get all open orders on a symbol.

    Args:
        symbol (str)
        recvWindow (int, optional)

    """
    params = {"symbol": symbol}
    params.update(kwargs)
    data = signedRequest("GET", "/api/v3/openOrders", params)
    return data


def allOrders(symbol, **kwargs):
    """Get all account orders; active, canceled, or filled.

    If orderId is set, it will get orders >= that orderId. Otherwise most
    recent orders are returned.

    Args:
        symbol (str)
        orderId (int, optional)
        limit (int, optional): Default 500; max 500.
        recvWindow (int, optional)

    """
    params = {"symbol": symbol}
    params.update(kwargs)
    data = signedRequest("GET", "/api/v3/allOrders", params)
    return data


def myTrades(symbol, **kwargs):
    """Get trades for a specific account and symbol.

    Args:
        symbol (str)
        limit (int, optional): Default 500; max 500.
        fromId (int, optional): TradeId to fetch from. Default gets most recent
            trades.
        recvWindow (int, optional)

    """
    params = {"symbol": symbol}
    params.update(kwargs)
    data = signedRequest("GET", "/api/v3/myTrades", params)
    return data


def request(method, path, params=None):
    resp = requests.request(method, ENDPOINT + path, params=params)
    data = resp.json()
    if "msg" in data:
        logging.error(data['msg'])
    return data


def signedRequest(method, path, params):
    if "apiKey" not in options or "secret" not in options:
        raise ValueError("Api key and secret must be set")

    query = urlencode(sorted(params.items()))
    query += "&timestamp={}".format(int(time.time() * 1000))
    secret = bytes(options["secret"].encode("utf-8"))
    signature = hmac.new(secret, query.encode("utf-8"),
                         hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    query += "&signature={}".format(signature)
    resp = requests.request(method,
                            ENDPOINT + path + "?" + query,
                            headers={"X-MBX-APIKEY": options["apiKey"]})
    data = resp.json()
    if "msg" in data:
        logging.error(data['msg'])
    return data


def formatNumber(x):
    if isinstance(x, float):
        return "{:.8f}".format(x)
    else:
        return str(x)
```

Any help or suggestions is appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

1. Uninstall, Reinstall, Upgrade.

   python -m pip uninstall python-binance

   python -m pip install python-binance

   python -m pip install --upgrade python-binance

**2. It looks like your binance.py file that you are writing is located in your site-packages. When you installed python-binance there was a folder created in your site-packages called binance**

You could move the file you are working on or rename the file you are working on.

this is what you are doing:

from binance.client import Client

this is what it means:

from the binance folder located in site_packages import the Client Class from the client.py file.

Since you have a binance.py it could be overriding the binance folder but im not sure why a module would be trying to import itself. Unless you are doing it differently.

Answer (score 5):

Had the wrong package installed

```
pip3 uninstall binance
pip3 install python-binance
```

Comment: I had the same issue. After uninstalling binance and installing python-binance, it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

This can happen when a directory in your project called "binance". Basically PyCharm will think that you are importing from directory instead of package itself.

Highly recommended not to name directories `binance` use other name.

Answer (score 3):

I changed the name of my folder from "binance" to "binance_mod" and this solved the issue.  I believe the error is with both the binance folder and binance.py file being in site-packages.

from there I just did

```
from binance_mod.client import Client
```

and I had no issues

Answer (score 2):

its my first time answering on stack overflow. I feel presure.

Had the same issue and took me some time to find it, in the new version of binance the renamed the function to set instead of Client, you can check that in you binance.py file and see it. when you do `set(apikey,secretkey)` it set a var called option with this two keys, once that done for each function call this var is used instead of the old function client (not sure what did the old function looked like)

another solution is by using an older version of python binance.

============================  EDIT

so i did this and it all worked well :

`!pip install python-binance==0.7.5`

Answer (score 1):

A very simple fix for me...just make sure your python code ***IS NOT saved in a file called binance.py***...

i renamed mine and it worked smoothly, seems the module requires that filename and that creates some conflict. Hope this helps

Comment: This has already been mentioned in other answers, such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/65725302/2227743

Answer (score 0):

You shuld rename binance.py to binance.client.py, at least I solved in this ways.
I found solution here: https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/issues/72

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using conda specifically to install twisted: (other sources didn't work)

```
conda install twisted
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error in my projects.The issues caused by file name. Chaning the name of the python file solved my issues.

file names like `binance.py` `platform.py` should be avoided.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a file named binance in your Direction change it to another name. It will Solve your Problem

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65725302/2227743) and other ones.

Answer (score -1):

This might be related to the security that your internet provider has in place.
After I changed my provider, I began getting such errors, however after contacting them and requesting to remove that extra internet protection everything runs without an issue.

Comment: ...how would this cause a `ModuleNotFoundError`? This is an import error, not an installation error.