# ModuleNotFoundError: NO module named 'binance.spot'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, modulenotfounderror

hello I'm running into a loop of errors when running a python code with all requirements installed, already try to python -m pip install python-binance and had no success

bellow the some of the loop errors

C:\Users\djino\Documents\Bot\Trading_Bot_9000 [main ≡]> python get_data.py sh run_signal.sh python tradebot.py
Execution of job "get_binance_btc_0m_data (trigger: interval[0:00:00.100000], next run at: 2022-10-20 10:00:01 BST)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)
Execution of job "get_binance_btc_0m_data (trigger: interval[0:00:00.100000], next run at: 2022-10-20 10:00:01 BST)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)
Execution of job "get_binance_btc_0m_data (trigger: interval[0:00:00.100000], next run at: 2022-10-20 10:00:01 BST)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)
Execution of job "get_binance_btc_0m_data (trigger: interval[0:00:00.100000], next run at: 2022-10-20 10:00:01 BST)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)
Execution of job "get_binance_btc_0m_data (trigger: interval[0:00:00.100000], next run at: 2022-10-20 10:00:01 BST)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)
Execution of job "get_binance_btc_0m_data (trigger: interval[0:00:00.100000], next run at: 2022-10-20 10:00:01 BST)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)
Job "get_binance_btc_0m_data (trigger: interval[0:00:00.100000], next run at: 2022-10-20 10:00:01 BST)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\apscheduler\executors\base.py", line 125, in run_job
retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
File "C:\Users\djino\Documents\Bot\Trading_Bot_9000\data_acquisition\get_binance_btc_0m.py", line 10, in get_binance_btc_0m_data
from binance.spot import Spot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'binance.spot'
Job "get_binance_btc_0m_data (trigger: interval[0:00:00.100000], next run at: 2022-10-20 10:00:01 BST)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\apscheduler\executors\base.py", line 125, in run_job
retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
File "C:\Users\djino\Documents\Bot\Trading_Bot_9000\data_acquisition\get_binance_btc_0m.py", line 10, in get_binance_btc_0m_data
from binance.spot import Spot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'binance.spot'
Job "get_binance_btc_0m_data (trigger: interval[0:00:00.100000], next run at: 2022-10-20 10:00:01 BST)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\apscheduler\executors\base.py", line 125, in run_job
retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
File "C:\Users\djino\Documents\Bot\Trading_Bot_9000\data_acquisition\get_binance_btc_0m.py", line 10, in get_binance_btc_0m_data
from binance.spot import Spot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'binance.spot'
Job "get_binance_btc_0m_data (trigger: interval[0:00:00.100000], next run at: 2022-10-20 10:00:01 BST)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\apscheduler\executors\base.py", line 125, in run_job
retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
File "C:\Users\djino\Documents\Bot\Trading_Bot_9000\data_acquisition\get_binance_btc_0m.py", line 10, in get_binance_btc_0m_data
from binance.spot import Spot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'binance.spot'
Job "get_binance_btc_1m_data (trigger: interval[0:00:01], next run at: 2022-10-20 10:00:02 BST)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\apscheduler\executors\base.py", line 125, in run_job
retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
File "C:\Users\djino\Documents\Bot\Trading_Bot_9000\data_acquisition\get_binance_btc_1m.py", line 6, in get_binance_btc_1m_data
from binance.spot import Spot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'binance.spot'
Job "get_binance_btc_3m_data (trigger: interval[0:00:01], next run at: 2022-10-20 10:00:02 BST)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\apscheduler\executors\base.py", line 125, in run_job
retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
File "C:\Users\djino\Documents\Bot\Trading_Bot_9000\data_acquisition\get_binance_btc_3m.py", line 6, in get_binance_btc_3m_data
from binance.spot import Spot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'binance.spot'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this problem ModuleNotFoundError: NO module named 'binance.spot'
install the module binance-connector

`pip install binance-connector`

docs here:https://binance-connector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

Αs @Tanner Martin mentioned here[Why am I getting this error 'ModuleNotFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59973858/why-am-i-getting-this-error-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-binance-clien)

You could

```
1.Uninstall, Reinstall, Upgrade.

python -m pip uninstall python-binance

python -m pip install python-binance

python -m pip install --upgrade python-binance
```

2. It looks like your binance.py file that you are writing is located in your site-packages. When you installed python-binance there was a folder created in your site-packages called binance

You could move the file you are working on or rename the file you are working on.

this is what you are doing:

from binance.client import Client

this is what it means:

from the binance folder located in site_packages import the Client Class from the client.py file.

Since you have a binance.py it could be overriding the binance folder but im not sure why a module would be trying to import itself. Unless you are doing it differently.

Comment: thanks but I just find the problem, to fix my problem I run `pip install binance-connector` and its working fine